# Enable Wireless link is not seen in Ubuntu 17.04 post installation

Tags: wireless, broadcom, 17.04

Enable Wireless link is not seen in Ubuntu 17.04 post installation on rome machine, hence I am not able to connect via WiFi

Refer https://pastebin.com/yk6LdJTJ for output from wireless-info

```
sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` I suspect it's secure boot.

Comment: @chili555 I just updated my response for modprobe